How to import html, css and js to Apps Script
Created a login and sign up form with design of container wrapper. First face is the login form which deployed fine but when I'm switching to signup form thru link located in the first face. the signup form doesn't show. Css design is working fine, the html also looks good to me. Might be the js code is the problem or the link thru signin form (take note that its not an actual link , what i mean is linked).
Form for Login and Signup, styled with wrapper. My problem is the first wrapper execute but my wrapper signup do not load. Once the code is fixed I will add a validation function for user management. This form will serves as the User Portal of EDMS.
Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate();
}

index.html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css').getContent(); ?>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Signin & Sign up</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="upage">

        <div class="form-container sign-up">
            <form id="signUpForm">
                <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                <span style="
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    color: #e85a4f;
                    font-style: italic;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-top: 5px;
                ">Welcome to Bounty's EDMS!</span>
                <div class="form-group" id="name">
                    <input type="text" id="nameInput" required>
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="email">
                    <input type="email" id="emailInput" required>
                    <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
                    <label for="emailInput">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="employeeId">
                    <input type="text" id="employeeIdInput" required>
                    <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                    <label for="employeeIdInput">Employee ID</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="password">
                    <input type="password" id="passwordInput" required>
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                    <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="checkFormAndTogglePopup()">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
                <div class="link" id="signInLink">
                    <p>You already have an account? <a href="#" class="signin-link">Sign In</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="form-container sign-in">
            <form action="#">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <span style="
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    color: #e85a4f;
                    font-style: italic;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-top: 5px;
                ">Great to see you again!</span>
                <div class="form-group" id="employeeIdr">
                    <input type="text" id="employeeIdInputSignIn" required>
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <label for="employeeIdInputSignIn">Employee ID</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="passwordr">
                    <input type="password" id="passwordInputSignIn" required>
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                    <label for="passwordInputSignIn">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="forgot-pass" id="forgotPassword">
                    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                <div class="link" id="signUpLink">
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#" class="signup-link">Sign Up</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="popup">
      <h3>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-check-circle" style='font-size:2.5rem;color:#1c9e08;position;center'></i> <br>
        You've successfully signed up for an <br> Electronic Document Management System account!
      </h3>
      <p>Please wait for an email confirmation to complete your account setup.<br> Once you receive the verification email, you may log in.</p>
      <a href="#" onclick="toggle"()></a>
    </div>

    <script>
        function togglePopup() {
            var upage = document.getElementById("upage");
            var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
            
            if (popup.classList.contains('active')) {
                popup.classList.add('transform-out');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    popup.classList.remove('active', 'transform-out');
                    upage.classList.remove('active');
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                upage.classList.add('active');
                popup.classList.add('active', 'transform-in');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    popup.classList.remove('transform-in');
                }, 1000);
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    togglePopup(); // Reload the page after a delay
                    window.location.reload();
                }, 5000);
            }
        }

        function checkFormAndTogglePopup() {
            const form = document.getElementById('signUpForm');
            if (form.checkValidity()) {
                togglePopup();
                form.reset(); // Clears the input fields
            } else {
                form.reportValidity();
            }
        }

        function toggleForm() {
            var signInForm = document.querySelector('.form-container.sign-in');
            signInForm.classList.toggle('active');
        }
        
    </script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9e5ba2e3f5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('js').getContent(); ?>

</body>

css.html (removed some parts of css)
<style>
  
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --mainColor: #9e0817;
    --whiteColor: #ffffff;
    --titleColor: #3d3d3d;
    --labelColor: #333333;
}


}

/* Popup active state */
#popup.active {
    visibility: visible; /* Make visible */
    opacity: 1; /* Make opaque */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1); /* Scale to normal size */
}

#popup h3 {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#popup h3 i {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#popup p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
}

/* Popup animations */
#popup.transform-in {
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease; /* Smooth transition for scaling in */
}

#popup.transform-out {
    transition: transform 1s ease, opacity 0.5s ease; /* Smooth transition for scaling out */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5); /* Scale down */
    opacity: 0; /* Fade out */
}

@keyframes signin-flip {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateX(-50rem) scale(1.1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0) rotate(7deg) scale(1);
    }
}

.wrapper.animated-signin .form-container.sign-up {
    animation: rotatecard .7s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes rotatecard {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(7deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(0);
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

.wrapper.animated-signup .form-container.sign-up {
    animation: signup-flip 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes signup-flip {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateX(50rem) scale(1.1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0) rotate(7deg) scale(1);
    }
}

.wrapper.wrapper.animated-signup .form-container.sign-in {
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    animation: rotatecard .7s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: .3s;
}

@keyframes rotatecard {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(7deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(0);
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

</style>

js.html
<script>

let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
    signUpLink = document.querySelector('.link .signup-link'),
    signInLink = document.querySelector('.link .signin-link');

signUpLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    wrapper.classList.add('animated-signin');
    wrapper.classList.remove('animated-signup');
});

signInLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    wrapper.classList.add('animated-signup');
    wrapper.classList.remove('animated-signin');
});

</script>

